what would be efficient way to to some job while waiting for a bash background process
I know how wait and & work but Instead of stalling at Wait Command I want to do some other job meanwhile.
For example this is my main code that sleeps for 10 seconds (background process).
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10 &
pid1=$!

./loading_bar.sh $pid1
echo "Finished Loading Stuff"
exit 0

While the main script sleeps for 10 seconds I print a Loading bar and in while loop check for Background process to finish. This Methods works perfectly but I would ask if there is any efficient way of doing this task as while (( 1 )); is a poor programming practice and can lead to infinite Looping if something goes wrong let's say the child process DEMONIZES or never exits for instance.
#!/bin/bash
proc_main=$1
tput civis
echo -e  "         ----------------------------------"
echo -ne "Loading |  "; tput sc;
echo -e            "                                 |"
echo -e  "         ----------------------------------"
tput rc
tput cuu1
tput cuu1
while (( 1 )); do
        for (( i=0; i<25; i++ )); do
                echo -ne "*";
                sleep 0.010
        done
        tput rc
        tput cuu1
        tput cuu1
        tput ech 25
        sleep 0.1
        if ! ps -p $proc_main > /dev/null; then
                echo "   Process Completed ! "
                break
        fi
done
echo -e ""
tput cnorm
``


Change while (( 1 )) to while pgrep -q -P $proc_main and get rid of the if ! ps ... block.

Why call pgrep or ps? Pass a PID and you can use while kill -0 "$pid"; do, which is shell-builtin.

BTW, echo -e is bad form; use printf '*' or printf '\n' (or, for the latter, just echo with no arguments at all) to improve portability / compatibility across different shells and shell configurations (even with the exact same version of bash, the xpg_echo flag -- which can be set via environment variable -- will change how echo -e works, so it's not reliable even if you're 100% sure which shell your script will be run with).

(Another performance note -- it'd be more efficient to just call your various tput commands that are used in the loop once before the loop starts and store their output in variables; you can then write those variables multiple times without the overhead of starting an external process).

BTW, if the child daemonizes the loop will end, because self-daemonization (which is, as an aside, bad practice in the modern world) involves doing a fork and having the initially-created process exit -- you get a grandchild in the background, but the direct child is exited.

The big inefficiencies here are the external command invocations -- ps and tput.
You don't need either to be within your loop; kill -0 can check whether a process is still running using only shell-builtin functionality, and you can store tput's output after calling it once to reuse as many times as you need.
tput_rc=$(tput rc)
tput_cuu=$(tput cuu1)
tput_ech25=$(tput ech25)

# note that we require proc_main to be a PID, not a process name
while kill -0 "$proc_main"; do
        for (( i=0; i<25; i++ )); do
                printf '*'
                sleep 0.010
        done
        printf %s "$tput_rc" "$tput_cuu1" "$tput_cuu1" "$tput_ech25"
        sleep 0.1
done
echo "   Process Completed ! "

